# How to compare 2 dataframes in pyspark based on dynamic columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes that I am processing in pyspark from different sources. These dataframes have few columns in common. Here is what I need to do,

- compare the 2 dataframes based on columns that are generated dynamically
- for matched rows, further process based on column values from both left and right
- also need unmatched records from both dataframes

Here is what I mean,

```
df1 = [Row(name=Bob, sub_id=1, id=1, age=5, status=active, version=0),
Row(name=Rob, sub_id=1, id=1, age=5, status=active, version=1),
Row(name=Tom, sub_id=2, id=3, age=50, status=active, version=0)]

df2 = [Row(name=Bobbie, sub_id=1, age=5),
Row(name=Tom, sub_id=2, age=51),
Row(name=Carter, sub_id=3, age=70)]
"""
my keys are based on sub_id and say they are per below,
  sub_id = 1, keys = [sub_id]
  sub_id = 2, keys = [sub_id, age]
  sub_id = 3, keys = [sub_id]
"""
#matched records expected results
#note that only sub_id=1 has a match based on keys. After match and further processing, version 0 record in df1 was copied as version 2 and updated per df2
df_matched = [
Row(name=Bobbie, sub_id=1, id=1, age=5, status=active, version=0), #updated per df2
Row(name=Rob, sub_id=1, id=1, age=5, status=active, version=1),
Row(name=Bob, sub_id=1, id=1, age=5, status=active, version=2) #new insert
]

#unmatched from df1
df_unmatched_left = [Row(name=Rob, sub_id=1, id=1, age=5, status=active, version=1)]

#unmatched from df2
df_unmatched_right = [Row(name=Tom, sub_id=2, age=51),
Row(name=Carter, sub_id=3, age=70)]

#Here is what I have tried so far
#created temp views of df1 and df2, say df1_table, df2_table
#but how do i make the joins dynamic and also further process for which i need both df1 and df2
df_matched = spark.sql("sql to join df1_table and df2_table").select("select from both dfs")  #use some function with map for further processing ? 

#to make the join condition, would using map and adding a temp column with join condition to use in query a good approach ?
```

I am using pyspark 2.3.x and python 3.5.x

Comment: Are the keys for sub_ids known?

Comment: I have a mapping for that. Something like {sub_id_1 : [list_of_keys]}